# Iterating over each element of a list inside of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, and have assigned multiple values to it like so -

```
d = {"names[]": ["System/CPU/User/percent", "System/CPU/System/percent"], "values[]": "average_value"}
```

I want the output to look like this -

```
names[]: System/CPU/User/percent
names[]: System/CPU/System/percent
values[]: average_value
```

How can I accomplish this?  The different for loop iterations that I have tried are not correctly parsing through the list.

Thanks.

Comment: Show what you've tried. Perhaps you are not iterating over the outer `dict` correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [2]: for k, v in d.iteritems():
   ...:     if isinstance(v, list):
   ...:         for s in v:
   ...:             print '{}: {}'.format(k, s)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print '{}: {}'.format(k, v)
   ...:
values[]: average_value
names[]: System/CPU/User/percent
names[]: System/CPU/System/percent
```